# How to replace text in database selecting more then 1 table

Tags: mysql, database, prestashop

I am trying to replace a text in a Prestashop database by selecting 2 columns so that the first column will be `id_lang` that contains value 1.

I don't really know how to explain it batter so I have made the screenshot below of what i am trying to do. `id_lang` contains all the languages for my website so 1= English.

What I want is to select just the column that contains 1 (English) and replace some text in the `description_short`.

[image]

Is there any way to do this? I was trying some methods that I found on SO but none of them are working.

Comment: Something like `UPDATE ps_product_lang SET description_short = 'new value' WHERE id_lang = 1`? What exactly do you want to replace there? Also have a look at MySQLs string replace function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: so right now the text for all languages is the same so i want to change it so for english to be in english and so on . Thanks for the quick answered

Comment: Worked ! Thanks THis is the final version in case someone will need it UPDATE ps_product_lang SET description_short = replace(description_short, 'text ', 'text to replace') WHERE id_lang = 8

Comment: As recommed in the Stackoverflow Meta, I'll write it as an answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update the columns using

`UPDATE ps_product_lang SET description_short = 'new value' WHERE id_lang = 1`

For certain replacements of existing values, you can use the `REPLACE` function of MySQL, too.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to Replace in your Tables. Here are 2 simple examples incase you might need them.

Update Single Column in Table:

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang 
SET 
    description_short = 'NEW SHORT DESCRIPTION',
WHERE
    id_lang = 1;
```

Update Multiple Columns in Table:

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang 
SET 
    description = 'NEW DESCRIPTION',
    description_short = 'NEW SHORT DESCRIPTION'
WHERE
    id_lang = 1;
```

A bit more info could be much helpfull about what you want to replace and with what. Good luck